# HTTP, sockets and null terminating character

Tags: http

Does the HTTP protocol specifies whether communication between client and server should include a null terminating character?

Comment: Do you mean that each HTTP message body should be terminated by `'\0'` like a C-style string?

Comment: @PJ.Hades Yeah, is that how it is?

Comment: I can't say that I'm extremely familiar with the protocol specification. But with some intuition, I think that HTTP does not require the `'\0'` ending. But you have to send and parse HTTP messages in the way the specification states. What's the source of this question? Problems in programming?